# Sending the results from a ForEach loop containing the Same SQL Query to 2 separate variables via PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell

Doing this query in sql server - it returns 3 rows of data.  Running the script with the write-host $1_resultsDataTable and comment out the other variable $2_resultsDataTable- it returns only one row of the data array.  Now if I reverse the comments so the $2_resultsDataTable is active for the write-host, it returns 6 rows of data.

How do I set this up so I would see the same 3 rows assigned to both $1_resultsDataTable and $2_resultsDataTable when I dump these variables to view the data results?

```
[string] $Server= "SERVER"
[string] $Database = "mvTest"
[string] $UserSqlQuery= $("select m.created_date, m.additional_data as ReasonDown from aeroscout.mv_audit m where m.created_date >= '2020-01-18' and m.additional_data like '%query-text%'")
#

$1_resultsDataTable, $2_resultsDataTable = foreach ($x in 1..2) {
    $resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery 
    $resultsDataTable # first loop sends output to $1_resultsDataTable, second loop send to $2_resultsDataTable
    Start-Sleep 3
} 

# executes a query and populates the $datatable with the data
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';Integrated Security=True;"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
If ($Reader.HasRows) {
   
  while($Reader.Read()) {
        $props = @{}
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $Reader.FieldCount; $i+=1) {
            $name = $Reader.GetName($i)
            $value = $Reader.item($i)
            $props.Add($name, $value)   
        }
        $obj = new-object PSObject -Property $props
        Write-Output $obj
      }
   }
     return $obj
$SqlConnection.Close()


}

#validate we got data
write-host $1_resultsDataTable
Start-Sleep 3
write-host $2_resultsDataTable
```

Comment: Your `ExecuteSqlQuery` seems to have duplicate output: `Write-Output $obj` and `return $obj`. Also, `$SqlConnection.Close()` is never executed because of the `return` statement and it should actually be `$Connection.Close()`.

Comment: thanks for capturing these 2 mistakes.  still wondering why I don't receive all 3 but only the last row with @ 5:38:37 - its like the first two rows are not stored in the resultsDataTables -----        
2020-03-03 04:00:22.500
2020-03-03 20:27:32.900
2020-03-06 05:38:37.300

Comment: I need to place all the rows found in one query run  and  store them like ----  $exportObject=@()   ForEach ($row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows) {
     $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date Created" -Value $row.created_date
        $exportObject += $ExciterObject

        }

Comment: Please Close Out - thanks working now

Comment: You should also remove the line `$resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable`.  It is not needed as it is completely replaced by whatever `ExecuteSqlQuery ` returns.

Comment: thanks - Daniel.  One thing that's really strange is the first variable results  with one row and the second variable with the remaining 5.  It should be 3 and repeat with the second with the other 3.

Comment: That is to be expected, due to `$1_resultsDataTable, $2_resultsDataTable = foreach`. When `foreach` returns an array, first variable will store the first array element and second variable will store all remaining array elements. Try this: `$a, $b = 1,2,3,4`. Now `$a` contains `1` and `$b` contains `2,3,4`. This is just how it works.

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle: in the `foreach` loop you output `$resultsDataTable`. This unrolls the array, so the `foreach` loop won't output two arrays as you propably expect, but a single array that is the concatenation of the two arrays. The loop isn't necessary, you can just do `$1_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery` and `$2_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery`. As other commenter wrote, the `New-Object` in the `foreach` loop is obsolete.